# Generate random points inside hollow sphere with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, random, probability

I have a function (copied from the MATLAB documentation) which generates random points inside a sphere. However, some points inside the sphere are not permissible. How can I generate random points inside a hollow sphere with permissible radius `1<r<2`. In other words, the points should lay on a radius of 1 to 2 so no points are allowed between r = [0 1].

EDIT: Completely forgot to include the function

```
function [x,y,z] = PointsInSphere(r,n)

rvals = 2*rand(n,1)-1;
elevation = asin(rvals);
azimuth = 2*pi*rand(n,1);
radii = r*(rand(n,1).^(1/r));
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(azimuth,elevation,radii);
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate random locations in 3D that are between the ball of radius 1 and that of radius 2?

Comment: @StackPlayer exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute the line

> `radii = r*(rand(n,1).^(1/r));`

by

```
x = (s/r)^r;
radii = r*(x+(1-x)*rand(n,1)).^(1/r);
```

where `r` is the outer radius and `s` is the inner radius (new function argument).

This replaces the (`0`,`1`)-uniform variable that was used for obtaining the radii in the original function by an (`x`,`1`)-uniform variable. The value `x` is computed such that the obtained radii have the original distribution but *truncated* to the interval (`s`,`r`). This ensures that the resulting 3D-distribution is *uniform* on the desired region.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 1.
Use the first as radius (add 1 to it so it is in [1,2]).
Multiply the second random number with 2pi.
Convert that from polar to Cartesian coordinates and you should be done.

Edit: do the same with a second angle to move to 3D.